# P-value for Intersection of three Circle Venn Diagram

Tags: r, p-value

[image]

I have a question for three circle venn diagram. Does anyone ever calculate the p value for overlapping region as show below Fig.
I have 4 RNA-seq samples (A, B, C and CT). In this dataset, I have 25633 genes  detected in all samples, and 3975, 2539, and 2818 genes were up/down-regulated in A, B and C sample, respectively. If 383 genes are in common for all three samples, what is the likelihood to have this situation by chance? How likely can the number of the intersection (middle part) of venn diagram occur by chance? How can I calculate the p value of this overlapping (383) part? Which statistics method can be use?
I would greatly appreciate it if anyone kindly give me some feedback.

Comment: In the absence of some postulated model governing the numbers in this diagram, the question is unanswerable.  Could you describe more explicitly--and quantitatively--what you mean by "chance" in this setting?  Are you perhaps supposing that $A$, $B$, and $C$ are independent events?

Answer (score 1):

I've tried while failed to deduce a formula to calculate the expected background distribution. Thus my practice to simply perform a simulation in silico via R.

```
s <- function(n,a,b,c){x <- sample(n,a);
    y <- sample(n,b);z <- sample(n,c);
    m <- c(c(x,y)[duplicated(c(x,y))],z);
    sum(duplicated(m))};
sum(replicate(10000,s(1:25633,3975,2818,2539)) >= 383)
```

Comment: base on your method, I get "0". Is this mean the p value is ~0?

Comment: Yes I think. At least it is estimated to be less than 1/10000, a rare incident.